# Why is jQuery ajax get returning a 404 Not found error even while the file exists on the server?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, jquery, http-status-code-404

When I access the following url via browser it works fine returning JSON data,

http://azcvoices.com/topcompanies/wp-content/themes/topcompanies/get.php?p=33

When jquery does an ajax `get` it is failing with a `404 Not found error` with the following code even when the file `get.php` truly exists on the server as mentioned above,

```
$.ajax( 
{
    url: "http://azcvoices.com/topcompanies/wp-content/themes/topcompanies/get.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {p: postId}
})
.done(function(post) {
})
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() {  });
```

You may see the 404 error below,
[image]

Currently the .htaccess has the following in it,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Could this be causing the issue?

The same demo on the test server at,
http://peplamb.com/workspace/azcentral.com/spotlight-stories/
works fine, but the same code is failing at http://azcvoices.com/topcompanies/spotlight-stories/

What could be the issue? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I visit that link in my browser, I get a 404...

Comment: could you try again? I was testing something!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you making the request from the same domain as the page is hosted on?  If not, you might be running into a problem with [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/).

To fix this, you might be able to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` as a header.

Comment: I don't think it took affect.  I'm not seeing it in the headers when I fetch the page.  EDIT- nevermind, appears to work now.

Comment: Hey Matt thanks for the quick response I added header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); to get.php file also went ahead and added AddType application/json .json to .htaccess file but still the same results any idea why?

Comment: Now can you can see it in the header?

Comment: Yes I can, and I can fetch it using AJAX.

Comment: i can see the data coming but its a 404 status code if you notice here  http://azcvoices.com/topcompanies/wp-content/themes/topcompanies/get.php?p=33

Comment: It looks like you are setting a weird status code.  It is a 404 status, but all of the data is coming through, so it seems to work fine.  `x = new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open("GET", "http://azcvoices.com/topcompanies/wp-content/themes/topcompanies/get.php?p=33"); x.send(null);` does return the proper data.

Comment: I know it does return perfect data when we test locally. As I said earlier, the same demo on the test server at, http://peplamb.com/workspace/azcentral.com/spotlight-stories/ works fine, but the same code is failing at http://azcvoices.com/topcompanies/spotlight-stories/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33173/discussion-between-matt-bryant-and-peplamb)

Comment: Thanks for the hint Matt!
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true, 200);
made it work!

Comment: Awesome - for some reason my local code needed this too!